# In a 2 col row in Bootstrap 5, remove all padding on one column but keep column 2 perfectly aligned

Tags: multiple-columns, bootstrap-5

So I've got a 2 column layout in Bootstrap 5 and each column needs to remain at 50% width e.g.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            One of two columns
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            One of two columns
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I wanted the content of the first col to be perfectly flush to the left and right hand edge of the column (no padding etc), but still keep the second column with the default padding, it would seem that if I simply did this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col p-0">
            One of two columns
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            One of two columns
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It makes column 1 slightly less wide and column 2 wider. Thus column 2 is out of alignment as both columns are no longer 50% in width.

To keep both columns the same width but have no padding on column 1, the only solution I can come up with is to then adjust the `flex` property on all columns within `.container-fluid` to increase the `flex-basis` value to an arbitrary amount below 50% e.g.

```
    .container-fluid .col { flex: 1 0 20%; }
```

This then has the desired effect and keeps both columns in alignment. But it feels a bit hacky.

I wonder if I've missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest bootstrap? It seems to work fine here. Both column contents are exactly the same width.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col p-0">
              One of two columns
          </div>
          <div class="col">
              One of two columns
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  </body>
      <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-kjU+l4N0Yf4ZOJErLsIcvOU2qSb74wXpOhqTvwVx3OElZRweTnQ6d31fXEoRD1Jy"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But the columns in your example are also not exactly the same width. Using your code, if I make my browser window say 1400px wide, then the first column is 688px and column 2 is 712px. Same in all browsers. 

In the end, the only other way I could fix this (which I subsequently prefer to my initial solution) was to set flex-basis: 50% on both columns. Then they are both 700px at 1400px browser window width.